# Theories of galaxy structure

Tags: newtonian-gravity, astrophysics, symmetry-breaking, galaxies, structure-formation

If you look up [galaxies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy) on Wikipedia (at least as of August 14, 2020) you will find a list of classes of galaxies that progresses roughly as follows:

1. Elliptical galaxies
2. Shell galaxies
3. Spiral galaxies
4. Barred spiral galaxies

Are there any theories for how these form? Is there a known sort of universality that could explain the observed classes?

Comment: whole books have been written about this; what has your own research uncovered?

Comment: Is there value in allowing students and physics majors to practice original expository writing on this website?

Comment: that is not what I was asking. Half of OP's questions have on-line answers that I found in 3 minute's worth of looking. I want to encourage looking.

Comment: This question is too broad, to answer it there's the entire field of "Galactic Evolution", which I won't introduce/resume in here. You should start looking for the term on the internet.